# Cannot install Microsoft Visual 2015

Tags: visual-studio

I get an error while I tried to reinstall Microsoft Visual 2015, Community Edition. I uninstalled it 1 week ago because I tried to install Microsoft SQL Server Management Tools, and I failed to install the correct version for 2015, and it also ruined my Microsoft Visual. I tried everything I find here or on the internet to make my Visual work because I need it as fast as possible. I'm a student for the moment. If you can help me solve this, as detailed as I can understand I would be very grateful. Thank you

[image]

[2]: Log File : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1V4c6lgwXCXclcQu0lHmmT4WnSDEAjaah/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Have you examined the log file, as the message suggests?

Comment: You don't need VS 2015 to use SSMS. SSMS is now a *separate free* [download](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms?view=sql-server-2017). Perhaps you should remove both SSMS and VS 2015 components and install the *latest* versions, VS 2017 Community and SSMS 17.7 ?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Perhaps I will do this, I was used to this version, and at the university we work with this, and that's why I didn't change it before.